# Custom aggregate initializer list constructor

Tags: c++, initialization, initializer-list, list-initialization

For example, [nlohmann json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) has a way of converting an aggregate initializer list to a JSON object:

```cpp
json j = {
  {"pi", 3.141},
  {"happy", true},
  {"name", "Niels"},
  {"nothing", nullptr},
  {"answer", {
    {"everything", 42}
  }},
  {"list", {1, 0, 2}},
  {"object", {
    {"currency", "USD"},
    {"value", 42.99}
  }}
};
```

and c++ `std::map` also has a aggeragte initalizer list

```cpp
{
{"one": 1},
{"two": 2}
}
```

I'm curious about how you can write a custom (aggregate) initalizer list initalizer

Comment: There is no such thing as an "aggregate initializer list" constructor. This is just an application of list-initialization. Each of those braced-init-lists is just a means for calling a constructor.

Comment: yes, but how do can i write a custom initializer for it (if I can)?

Comment: You can look inside json.hpp to see how it writes its constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to learn howtos in the standard library.

Look at the [`std::map` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map):

```
map( std::initializer_list<value_type> init,
     const Compare& comp = Compare(),
     const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

[`value_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is

```
std::pair<const Key, T>, Key is std::string, T is int
```

So the constructor is

```
map( std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, int>> init,
     const Compare& comp = Compare(),
     const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

and can be used like with

```
{
  std::pair("one", 1),
  std::pair("two", 2),
}
```

Then look at [`std::pair` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair)

```
pair( const T1& x, const T2& y );
```

It can be constructed like

```
std::pair<std::string, int> a{"one", 1};
```

or

```
std::pair<std::string, int> a = {"one", 1};
```

Taking into consideration all above, a map can be constructed like with

```
{
{"one", 1},
{"two", 2}
}
```

Comment: what about the more complex JSON example? if you can explain it, ill accept your answer!

Comment: @FloweyTF: It's the same thing, just using a different type. It's nothing special. Just look at the `json` type's constructor.

Comment: More complex JSON can be done with `std::map<std::string, std::any>`

Comment: Or `class JSONItem : public std::variant<std::string, bool, int, std::map<std::string, JSONItem>, std::vector<JSONItem>> {};

using JSON = std::map<std::string, JSONItem>;`

Comment: I'd rather not use std::variant because its for c++17, but I guess?